# how to understand <(echo) in this command line?

Tags: awk

this line collapse file base on the first column.

```
awk '{if($1==x){i=i" "$2}else{if(NR>1){print i};i=$0};x=$1;y=$2}' test.cov <(echo)
```

input:

```
1001  hisk01
1001  hisk02
1001  hisk03
1002  hisk04
1002  hisk05
1002  hisk06
1003  hisk07
1003  hisk08
```

output:

```
1001 hisk01 hisk02 hisk03
1002 hisk04 hisk05 hisk06
1003 hisk07 hisk08
```

It works, but I don't know how does the `<(echo)` work here. Could anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: As @Kaz's answer below says, `<(echo)` is using a feature available in **some** shells (including ksh, bash, zsh) called process substitution.  You can read a good, short definition of it on wikipedia's [Process Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) page.

Answer (score 2):

`<(` is "process substitution", which is a feature of the GNU Bourne-Again Shell (Bash). It is not in POSIX.

Process substitution is a piece of syntax that expands to a command line argument. The target program can open the argument as if it were the name of a file. The resulting file descriptor is connected to the command pipe indicated in the syntax between the parentheses.

So that is to say, `<(echo)` expands to some word like `/magic/path/53`. When the program receives this path and opens it for a file as input, it gets a pipe descriptor that reads from `echo`.

What does `echo` do? It produces an empty line.

The only difference between

```
some-command <(echo)
```

and

```
some-command /dev/null
```

is that `<(echo)` produces an empty line, whereas `/dev/null` produces nothing.

You can pretend that `<(echo)` is the path name of a file that contains one empty line (as long as that path name is opened only for input, not output).

Here, the idea seems to be to ensure that the input to `awk` contains a terminating blank line. That is to say, no matter what is in the input file `test.cov`, there will be
an additional blank line. The script's logic requires it because it maintains state between successive lines. There is a variable `i` whose contents depend on the previous line and are printed when the next line arrives. The `i` which is calculated for the last line is never printed, so without an extra blank line coming from `<(echo)`, the last line of `test.cov` will not be fully processed.

Note that if `test.cov` is missing a terminating newline, then the `<(echo)` will not simply supply that newline; multiple input files to awk are not simply catenated together into one character stream. A record will be delimited at the end of the first file, whether or not a newline is present, and the second file produces a new record.

There is a simple way to remove the dependency on the process substitution feature from the surrounding shell:

```
awk '{if($1==x){i=i" "$2}else{if(NR>1){print i};i=$0};x=$1;y=$2}; END {print i}'
```

That's it! We add an `END` block which prints any accumulated `i`. We don't need the `NR > 1` test there, because if `NR == 0`, it means no records have been processed, and so `i` is undefined, printing as nothing. However, an empty blank line is output in that case, which can be avoided using `END {if (i) print i}`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Also , is the "y=$2" disposable, since it's not referred elsewhere.

Comment: @Yuxiangli that `y` was supposed to be used here `i=i" "$2` instead of `$2`, but using less temp variables is fine, so you can remove `y=$2` from your code safely as it's redundant.

Comment: `y` serves no purpose. Using it instead of `$2` in calculating `i` would be incorrect because that's the `$2` of the previous record.

Answer (score 2):

That just causes to output the last content buffered in`i` variable. That produces an empty line so it causes to awk run once more for that empty line and so it will output the buffered value in the `i` variable. instead of `<(echo)` you could use the `END{ print i }` block.

See also [my this answer](/a/647816/72456) to how you could do this in another ways in both cases where your input is sorted/unsorted.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Hi, I am also curious about why the END {print i} doesn't break the run of awk. Could you please elaborate more about this?

Comment: @Yuxiangli why that should break? The END block runs only once after awk proceed all the input lines from its input. that's `exit` statement that break the awk from running, read more about that here https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html

Comment: it states END will only run once, so I don't understand why END{print i } can constantly print the results of each different "i" out. I thought END{print i} would only print the result of last line or last "i"

Comment: read my answer again, I said _"`instead of <(echo) you could use the END{ print i } block.`"_, not inplace of all your script

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for the chain questions, I get it that  awk '{if($1==x){i=i" "$2}else{if(NR>1){print i};i=$0};x=$1}; END {print i}' works well, but just confused why that the END block works. Because usually I use END block, which only give me one last output, But here it actively output.

Comment: @Yuxiangli don't you know what commmad are you running? you can see that there is a `if(NR>1){print i}` part that is printing something.... it's not only the END  block print everything, the END block only print the last value of the `i` variable nothing else. if still don't know about how END works, see the given manual about END block again.

Answer (score 0):

You got an answer to the question you asked but FYI one of the more common ways to do what you're trying to do is just:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '$1!=prev{print rec; ORS=RS; rec=prev=$1} {rec=rec OFS $2} END{print rec}' file
1001 hisk01 hisk02 hisk03
1002 hisk04 hisk05 hisk06
1003 hisk07 hisk08
```

Comment: Or something like `datamash -W -g 1 collapse 2 <file` (but you'll get comma-delimited values).